# devexpress magic. Adding a new column leads to a differend fieldname which never was added

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am new to devexpress and want to add a second column with fieldname "zugang". However it is always displayed some total different fieldname called "AnlagekontoBezeichnung" which I never added. Can someone explain this? Here is the code

```
>             columnDefinitions.Add(
>                 new GridColumnDefinitionModel
>                 {
>                     FieldName = "AnlagekontoNummer",
>                     GroupIndex = 1,
>                     Header = "Anlagekonto",
>                     VisibleIndex = 0,
>                     EditSettings =
>                         new TextEditSettings
>                         {
>                             HorizontalContentAlignment = EditSettingsHorizontalAlignment.Right
>                         }
>                 });
>             columnDefinitions.Add(
>                 new GridColumnDefinitionModel
>                 {
>                     FieldName = "Zugang",
>                     Header = "Zugang",
>                     VisibleIndex = 4,
>                     EditSettings = new TextEditSettings
>                     {
>                         DisplayFormat = "N2"
>                     }
>                 });
```

[image: Here is a pickture from debugger]

Comment: Which DevExpress product are you using? They make grids for WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, HTML5/JS, Xamarin... please be more specific about what environment you are working in.

Comment: oh ok, here it is: DevExpress WPF Control v.19.2.5

Comment: What happens if you switch Anlagekonto and Zugang columns? What happens if you don't add Anglagekonto?